# java.io.FileNotFoundException while opening input stream in android HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I am working in application all requests are working except one request give me the following error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: baseURL/MyListings/editListing
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
at com.forsale.forsale.controller.manager.ForSaleNetworkManager.execute(ForSaleNetworkManager.java:137)
at com.forsale.forsale.controller.manager.ForSaleServerManager$37.doInBackground(ForSaleServerManager.java:2820)
at com.forsale.forsale.controller.manager.ForSaleServerManager$37.doInBackground(ForSaleServerManager.java:2795)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I really don't know what is the problem.

**EDIT**

The request is working on postman

Comment: check file path FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File not found exception occurs because of misspelled method name.

Please share links of postman & used in code which is better to understand.

Check response code 200 of success

```
if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    json = readStream(in);
}else {
    json = "{\"result\":\"fail\"}";
}
```

Comment: urlConnection.getResponseCode()  give me 442

Comment: The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server understands the content type of the request entity and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate)